# Dirty flag for Custom Property Page with VSX

Tags: vsx

I have a custom package created as Visual Studio Extension. For my project file, I created two new custom property pages. Only these two are shown in the property window of my project. Everything works fine with the Dirty flag on property page level, meaning that, when I change something, the single tab is set dirty, and when the information is stored, it goes back to not dirty.

But my problem is: As soon as I open the property pages, the main Tab of the view (where the project name is displayed) contains the dirty flag (a little star) and I can't manage to solve this problem. Which property do I have to set where to "not dirty", so that the complete page is shown as "not dirty".

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

I remember that there were some related threads on MSDF Forums (Visual Studio Extensibility) -  see them [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/vstudio?query=isdirty%20marker%20property%20page&rq=meta%3aSearch.MSForums.ForumID%28a6b3f7be-4a18-4637-a55a-41b5596cd903%29%20site%3amicrosoft.com&rn=Visual%20Studio%20Extensibility%20Forum&ac=8).

I am not sure already, but the sample I posted on MSDN Forums (VSX Forum) in '[Need sample code for custom property pages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/a7dd61b8-8c51-47ba-933c-8805b0a8665a/)' thread worked OK for me.

P.S. And you always could report the [VSX bug on Microsoft Connent](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

See the Custom Property Page sample below, and the rest related code samples are also available in MSDN thread I mentioned above.

```
1   using System; 
2   using System.Diagnostics; 
3   using System.Drawing; 
4   using System.IO; 
5   using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
6   using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
7   using System.Windows.Forms; 
8    
9   namespace MyProjectProperties 
10  { 
11      [Guid(Guids.RealCustomPropertyPageGuidString)] 
12      public partial class RealCustomPropertyPage : CustomPropertyPage 
13      { 
14          ...  
15  
16          #region Constructors 
17   
18          public RealCustomPropertyPage() 
19              : base() 
20          { 
21              InitializeComponent(); 
22              Title = ResMgr.GetString(TextKeys.RealCustomPropertyPageCaption); 
23          } 
24  
25          #endregion 
26  
27  
28          #region Overriden Methods 
29   
30          protected override void Initialize() 
31          { 
32              AddComboBoxItems(cboOutputType, OutputTypeManager.Application, OutputTypeManager.Library); 
33              AddComboBoxItems(cboTargetVersion, TargetVersionManager.Flash7, TargetVersionManager.Flash8); 
34   
35              txtAssemblyName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
36              txtDefaultNamespace.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
37              txtMainClass.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
38              txtInputSwfLocation.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnRefreshControlStateChanged); 
39              txtOutputPath.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
40              txtFrameParameter.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
41              txtFrameRate.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
42              txtWidth.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
43              txtHeight.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
44              txtColorPreview.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnColorPreviewChanged); 
45              txtAdditionalParams.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
46   
47              cboOutputType.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnRefreshControlStateChanged); 
48              cboTargetVersion.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
49   
50              chkInputSwfLocation.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnRefreshControlStateChanged); 
51              chkKeepParameter.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
52              chkFrameParameter.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
53              chkUsePrecompiledMxClasses.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
54              chkUseTypeInference.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
55              chkUseStrictCompilation.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(OnPropertyChanged); 
56   
57              btnBrowseInputSwf.Click += new EventHandler(OnBrowseInputSwfClicked); 
58              btnBrowseMainClass.Click += new EventHandler(OnBrowseMainClassClicked); 
59              btnSelectBackgroundColor.Click += new EventHandler(OnSelectBackgroundColorClicked); 
60              btnSetOutputPath.Click += new EventHandler(OnBrowseOutputPathClicked); 
61   
62              RefreshControlState(); 
63          } 
64   
65          protected override void FillProperties() 
66          { 
67              Fill(txtAssemblyName, Property.AssemblyName); 
68              Fill(txtDefaultNamespace, Property.DefaultNamespace); 
69              Fill(txtMainClass, Property.MainClass); 
70              Fill(txtOutputPath, Property.AsOutputPath); 
71              Fill(txtInputSwfLocation, Property.InputSwfLocation); 
72              Fill(txtFrameParameter, Property.FrameParameter); 
73              Fill(txtFrameRate, Property.FrameRate); 
74              Fill(txtWidth, Property.Width); 
75              Fill(txtHeight, Property.Height); 
76              Fill(txtAdditionalParams, Property.AdditionalParams); 
77   
78              Fill(lblColorPreview, Property.BackgroundColor); 
79   
80              Fill(cboTargetVersion, Property.TargetVersion); 
81              Fill(cboOutputType, Property.OutputType); 
82   
83              Fill(chkInputSwfLocation, Property.UseInputSwf); 
84              Fill(chkKeepParameter, Property.KeepInputClasses); 
85              Fill(chkFrameParameter, Property.UseFrameParameter); 
86              Fill(chkUsePrecompiledMxClasses, Property.UsePrecompiledMxClasses); 
87              Fill(chkUseTypeInference, Property.UseTypeInference); 
88              Fill(chkUseStrictCompilation, Property.UseStrictCompilation); 
89          } 
90   
91          protected override bool CheckInput() 
92          { 
93              bool valid = true; 
94   
95              valid &= CheckSwfInputFileValid(); 
96              valid &= CheckFrameRateValid(); 
97              valid &= CheckWidthValid(); 
98              valid &= CheckHeightValid(); 
99              valid &= CheckFrameValid(); 
100             valid &= CheckOutputPathValid(); 
101  
102             return valid; 
103         } 
104  
105         protected override void ApplyChanges() 
106         { 
107             bool needReParse = GetComboValue(cboTargetVersion) != GetProperty(Property.TargetVersion); 
108  
109             Apply(txtAssemblyName, Property.AssemblyName); 
110             Apply(txtDefaultNamespace, Property.DefaultNamespace); 
111             Apply(txtMainClass, Property.MainClass); 
112             Apply(txtOutputPath, Property.AsOutputPath); 
113             Apply(txtInputSwfLocation, Property.InputSwfLocation); 
114             Apply(txtFrameParameter, Property.FrameParameter); 
115             Apply(txtFrameRate, Property.FrameRate); 
116             Apply(txtWidth, Property.Width); 
117             Apply(txtHeight, Property.Height); 
118             Apply(txtAdditionalParams, Property.AdditionalParams); 
119  
120             Apply(lblColorPreview, Property.BackgroundColor); 
121  
122             Apply(cboOutputType, Property.OutputType); 
123             Apply(cboTargetVersion, Property.TargetVersion); 
124  
125             Apply(chkInputSwfLocation, Property.UseInputSwf); 
126             Apply(chkKeepParameter, Property.KeepInputClasses); 
127             Apply(chkFrameParameter, Property.UseFrameParameter); 
128             Apply(chkUsePrecompiledMxClasses, Property.UsePrecompiledMxClasses); 
129             Apply(chkUseTypeInference, Property.UseTypeInference); 
130             Apply(chkUseStrictCompilation, Property.UseStrictCompilation); 
131  
132             // Re-parse with new target type applied 
133             if (needReParse && SettingManager.EnableIntelliSense && NeutronKeeper.Registered) 
134             { 
135                 string property = GetProperty(Property.TargetVersion); 
136                 string directory = TargetVersionManager.DefineDirectory(property); 
137                 Debug.Assert(Directory.Exists(directory)); 
138  
139                 SymbolTable cache = ((AsProjectNode)ProjectMgr).GetCache(); 
140                 cache.ParseSourcesFromDirectory(directory, true, true); 
141             } 
142         } 
143 
144         #endregion 
145 
146 
147         #region Private Methods 
148  
149         private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
150         { 
151             MarkPageChanged(); 
152         } 
153  
154         private void OnRefreshControlStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
155         { 
156             RefreshControlState(); 
157             MarkPageChanged(); 
158         } 
159  
160         private void OnBrowseOutputPathClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
161         { 
162             FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog(); 
163  
164             string projectDir = GetProperty(Property.MSBuildProjectDirectory); 
165             PropertyHelper.SetPaths(dialog, projectDir, txtOutputPath.Text); 
166  
167             if (DialogResult.OK == dialog.ShowDialog()) 
168             { 
169                 txtOutputPath.Text = PathHelper.MakeRelative(projectDir, dialog.SelectedPath); 
170                 MarkPageChanged(); 
171             } 
172         } 
173  
174         private void OnSelectBackgroundColorClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
175         { 
176             ColorDialog dialog = new ColorDialog(); 
177             dialog.Color = lblColorPreview.BackColor; 
178             if (DialogResult.OK == dialog.ShowDialog()) 
179             { 
180                 SetColorPreview(lblColorPreview, dialog.Color); 
181                 MarkPageChanged(); 
182             } 
183         } 
184  
185         private void OnBrowseMainClassClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
186         { 
187             OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog(); 
188             dialog.Title = ResMgr.GetString(TextKeys.BrowseMainClassTitle); 
189             dialog.Filter = ResMgr.GetString(TextKeys.BrowseMainClassFilter); 
190  
191             string projectDir = GetProperty(Property.MSBuildProjectDirectory); 
192             PropertyHelper.SetPaths(dialog, projectDir, txtMainClass.Text); 
193  
194             if (DialogResult.OK == dialog.ShowDialog()) 
195             { 
196                 txtMainClass.Text = PathHelper.MakeRelative(projectDir, dialog.FileName); 
197                 OnPropertyChanged(sender, e); 
198             } 
199         } 
200  
201         private void OnBrowseInputSwfClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
202         { 
203             OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog(); 
204             dialog.Title = ResMgr.GetString(TextKeys.BrowseInputSwfTitle); 
205             dialog.Filter = ResMgr.GetString(TextKeys.BrowseInputSwfFilter); 
206  
207             string projectDir = GetProperty(Property.MSBuildProjectDirectory); 
208             PropertyHelper.SetPaths(dialog, projectDir, txtInputSwfLocation.Text); 
209  
210             if (DialogResult.OK == dialog.ShowDialog()) 
211             { 
212                 txtInputSwfLocation.Text = PathHelper.MakeRelative(projectDir, dialog.FileName); 
213                 OnPropertyChanged(sender, e); 
214             } 
215         } 
216  
217         private void OnColorPreviewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
218         { 
219             Match match = _hexColorRegex.Match(txtColorPreview.Text.Trim()); 
220             if (match.Success) 
221             { 
222                 SetColorPreview(lblColorPreview, HexStringToColor(match.Captures[0].Value)); 
223             } 
224         } 
225  
226         private void RefreshControlState() 
227         { 
228             // Input swiff file block related 
229             bool allowToSelectInputSwf = chkInputSwfLocation.Checked; 
230             bool isInputSwfHasValue = txtInputSwfLocation.Text.Trim().Length > 0; 
231  
232             txtInputSwfLocation.Enabled = allowToSelectInputSwf; 
233             btnBrowseInputSwf.Enabled = allowToSelectInputSwf; 
234             chkKeepParameter.Enabled = allowToSelectInputSwf && isInputSwfHasValue; 
235             chkUsePrecompiledMxClasses.Enabled = allowToSelectInputSwf && isInputSwfHasValue; 
236  
237             // Application settings group related 
238             gbxApplicationSettings.Enabled = (GetComboValue(cboOutputType) == OutputTypeManager.Application); 
239         } 
240  
241         private bool CheckFrameRateValid() 
242         { 
243             return IsPositiveInteger(txtFrameRate.Text, "Invalid Frame Rate value."); 
244         } 
245  
246         private bool CheckFrameValid() 
247         { 
248             return IsPositiveInteger(txtFrameParameter.Text, "Invalid Target Frame value."); 
249         } 
250  
251         private bool CheckHeightValid() 
252         { 
253             return IsPositiveInteger(txtHeight.Text, "Invalid Height value."); 
254         } 
255  
256         private bool CheckWidthValid() 
257         { 
258             return IsPositiveInteger(txtWidth.Text, "Invalid Width value."); 
259         } 
260  
261         private bool IsPositiveInteger(string toParse, string errorMessage) 
262         { 
263             try 
264             { 
265                 uint.Parse(toParse); 
266             } 
267             catch 
268             { 
269                 _logger.Info(errorMessage); 
270                 MessageBox.Show(errorMessage); 
271                 return false; 
272             } 
273             return true; 
274         } 
275  
276         private bool CheckSwfInputFileValid() 
277         { 
278             ...  
279         } 
280  
281         private bool CheckOutputPathValid() 
282         { 
283             ...  
284         } 
285  
286         private void Fill(Label label, Property property) 
287         { 
288             string backgroundColor = ProjectMgr.GetProjectProperty(property.ToString(), true); 
289             SetColorPreview(label, HexStringToColor(backgroundColor)); 
290         } 
291  
292         private void SetColorPreview(Label label, Color color) 
293         { 
294             txtColorPreview.Text = label.Text = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color); 
295             label.BackColor = color; 
296         } 
297  
298         private void Apply(Label acceptor, Property property) 
299         { 
300             string hexString = ColorToHexString(acceptor.BackColor); 
301             ProjectMgr.SetProjectProperty(property.ToString(), hexString); 
302         } 
303  
304         private string FilterDirectoryPath(string dirPath) 
305         { 
306             if (dirPath.Split(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()).Length > 1) 
307             { 
308                 dirPath = dirPath.Trim(); 
309                 foreach(char invalidCharacter in Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) 
310                 { 
311                     dirPath = dirPath.Replace(invalidCharacter.ToString(), string.Empty); 
312                 } 
313             } 
314             return dirPath; 
315         } 
316 
317 
318         #region HEX <-> Color convertions 
319  
320         ... skipped ... 
321 
322         #endregion 
323 
324 
325         #endregion 
326     } 
327 }
```